# Android Host : connection with a Mass storage USB device

Tags: android, usb, host

I am currently trying to develop an application who access xml files on an usb device.
I have read the Google Documentation about Android USB Host.
Now i can detect my USB Device, discover its specifications (like PID/VID), but i can't access on the files of the USB device :(

Here is my code of the activity looking for devices :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_visu);


  affichage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.afficher);
  context = VisuActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
  UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
  HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();

  Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

  if(deviceList.size()==1){
      while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
             device = deviceIterator.next();

      }

      UsbInterface mUsbInterface = device.getInterface(0);
      UsbEndpoint endpoint = mUsbInterface.getEndpoint(0);

      UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);

   }
}
  /* What To Do Now ???? */
```

I have tried to find some example on the internet, but I am lost now ! :(

Anyone knows how to do for read (and eventually write) a file on a USB device ?
I have heard that there is a Mass Storage protocol to follow, but i don't find or understand it !

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, it's just a guess. But I would assume that the kernel would be mount any Mass Storage device on your system somewhere inside `/mnt/` so you can just access stuff in there with the normal 'File' class

Comment: Yes, I have already look in that way, but there is nothing in the   `/mnt/` File, or even if in the path descripted by the UsbDevice Object : `\dev\bus\usb\002`  ! Or just a `*.o` File

Comment: I'd be interested in a solution too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android detect usb storage for kitkat (4.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208297/android-detect-usb-storage-for-kitkat-4-4).  There I posted solutions for pre-6.0 and 6.0/above.

Answer (score -1):

Listen to intent filter

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
 </intent-filter>
```

above filter won't show that a usb file is mount but you will be notified as some mass storage is mount but i guess after getting usb attached receiver you are pretty much sure mounted device is usb mass storage

so when the usb mass storage is mounted you will get notified

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        File file=new File("/storage/usbdisk");
                File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
                for ( File f : listFiles){
                    f.getAbsoluteFilePath()
                    //you can do all file processing part here
                }
    }
}
```

file path for usb is not standard so you can list all file in "/storage"
if the file name contains "usb" then its usb for sure in my case "/storage/usbdisk "